# Xamarin.forms: Unable to connect to locally hosted web service

Tags: rest, web-services, xamarin.forms

I've asked this in [xamarin forums](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/120620/xamarin-forms-unable-to-connect-to-locally-hosted-web-service); but didn't get any response.
I've been trying to connect with web service deployed in my local (which is running in tomcat). And I'm deploying my project in physical Android device. As you can see in the code below that I've used my local PC's IP address. Also in Android Manifest file, I turned on the "INTERNET" permission. If I run this url directly from the web browser, I get expected result.

`
public async Task getHospitalsByCityAsync(string city){
    List hospitals = null;

```
    string RestUrl = "192.168.15.100:8080/unsaarAPI/bismillah/city/" + city;
    var uri = new Uri(RestUrl);

    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            NswHospitalSearch nswHs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NswHospitalSearch>(content);
            hospitals = nswHs.hospitals;
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(@"              ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
    }
    return hospitals;
}`
```

During debug, its doesn't reach at line if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) and after a while I get
Error: ConnectFailure (Connection timed out)

I've no clue how to fix this. I've been surfing online many hours; but can't find a suitable solution.
Can any one help. I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: did you test in the device's browser?  Are you sure there aren't any firewall issues on your server?

Comment: @Jason, You were right, I can't access it from my device's browser or from different laptop. I don't see any firewall on my tomcat-9 server. Also I tried by disabling my PC's windows-10 firewall. still no luck.

Comment: is your device on the same subnet as the server?  This is a networking issue, not a programming one